# I am trying to get some values from oracle sqlplus and i want the values between 550000 and 56000

Tags: sqlplus

I am trying this particular query below to get some values, this is giving me values ranging from 200000 to 600000, but suppose the 4th row does not hold any value. Example:

556789

348888

456678

null

577766

456789

Above the 4th row i have written as null here. I want to remove this row from output. How can i structure the below query, to remove the null row. Please help on this.

```
select distinct r.foreignEditId from relationalConditionTable r, conditionNameTable c where c.conditionName like 'VPI' and c.foreignEditId = r.editId;
```

Answer (score 0):

add an additional condition in your query:

```
AND c.foreignEditId IS NOT NULL
```

... and you got rid of that NULL entries